# Word Template - Disappearing Text

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I am working on a solution where i will take an existing word template, from a business unit, and replace dollar amounts with content placeholders.

When i was provided the MS Word document (.doc) i converted it to a .docx.

I noticed that entering and leaving design mode caused large paragraphs to appear and disappear, there does not seem to be any content placeholders.

Any idea what this feature is?  I have searched for a couple of hours with no success.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I am not very familiar with Word documents. My solution uses OpenXML and inspection of the xml reveals a "Vanish" tag. This indicates text that has been marked as hidden. Highlight the text and hit CNTRL + D to bring up the font dialog box and unmark your text as "Hidden"

Hope this saves someone else in the future.